# Sync state between main window and sub windows in flutter

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I want to sync state between main window and sub windows in flutter project.
As you know, I can create several windows using desktop_multi_window package.
At that time, I want to use same state in all windows - main window and sub windows.
In other words, if I click button in main window to change state and it has to reflect to sub windows.
How can I solve this?
I am using riverpod for state management.

I thought it will work without doing any extra work.

Comment: That's exactly how statemanagement creates an MVC separation.  You have one model, and multiple views.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a controller like this:

```
@riverpod
class IsValidBirthdayController extends _$IsValidBirthdayController {
  @override
  bool build() {
    return false;
  }
}
```

listen to its changes by:

```
ref.watch(isValidBirthdayControllerProvider)
```

Change its by:

```
ref.watch(isValidBirthdayControllerProvider.notifier).state = false;
```

Comment: This is the part of main.dart file.
As you know, if I create new window using desktop_multi_window, it calls main function again.

void main() {
if (args.firstOrNull == 'multi_window') runApp(ChildApp());
else runApp(MainApp());
}

I want to sync state of MainApp and ChildApp